# Expected value alternative formula with Tonelli's theorem - question about proof

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The task is to prove that
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}(X>x)dx
$$

Proof:

If X is nonnegative random variable then for every $\omega \in \Omega$,
$$
X(\omega) = \int_0^{X(\omega)}dx = \int_0^\infty \mathbb1_{(0, X(\omega)]}(x)dx
$$

Then plugging in
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \int_\Omega X d\mathbb{P} = \int_\Omega \int_0^\infty \mathbb1_{(0, X(\omega)]}(x)dx d\mathbb{P}
$$

now, since $X \geq 0$ and $\mathbb1_{(0, X(\omega)]} \geq 0$ we are using Tonelli's theorem to obtain:
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_\Omega \mathbb1_{(0, X(\omega)]}(x)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)dx = \int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}(X>x)dx
$$
q.e.d.

Could anyone explain the following identity, used as the last step:
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_\Omega \mathbb1_{(0, X(\omega)]}(x)d\mathbb{P}(\omega)dx = \int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}(X>x)dx
$$
Seems like basic measure theory task but I can't wrap my mind around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1_{(0,X(\omega))} (x)=1$ iff $x < X(\omega)$ iff $X(\omega ) >x$ and $0$ otherwise so the integral is equal to  $\int_{\Omega} 1_{X(\omega) >x)} dP(\omega) =P(X>x)$.

BTW you should use $(0,X(\omega))$ rather than $(0,X(\omega)]$ in this proof.

Comment: I got it from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value - somebody used $(0, X(\omega)]$ there.

Comment: @math_beginner You can use the half closed interval also but the formula you get will be slightly different: you will get $EX=\int P(X \geq x)dx$. This formula is also correct.